# How to ping a vm on a machine from a vm on another machine?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos

I have 2 centos 7 VMs on my laptop. They can ping each other and the host. However, I am unable to ping a VM on another laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If the VM on the other laptop that you are trying to ping is using NAT for its network connection, it is not going to be reachable.  If possible in the VM host on the other laptop change the network type to bridged.  Check and see if the client got a new IP address.  If you are using DHCP you might need to caused the guest OS to release and renew the DHCP address or rebooting the guest OS.  If you are using static IP addresses, be sure to use one that is on the same subnet as the host OS.  There could also be host firewall setting that need to be openned to allow access.  As the host OS and guest OS were not specified instruction for the specifics can't be provided, but should be able to be found with a search for the OS and/or firewall in use.